# How Xpages - Create pages animation

Tags: dojo, xpages

Is Xpages possible to create animation "table" pages.

**For example:**
There have 4 image file moving inside a table content and will change each image on 3-4 second.

Notes: If i din't use .gif as a moving object. Do Xpages have their own way to create?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But can you show us some of your code examples, or describe what you have tried already to create a Slideshow?

Comment: you could have a look at Marky Roden's Xomino project, where he among other things describes an Xpages based slideshow created with jQuery: http://xomino.com/2012/04/03/jquery-in-xpages-4-prettyphoto/

Comment: Google "JavaScript carousel".

Answer (score 1):

The XPages runtime uses Dojo for client side rendering as default. Any element in a page can be given a dojo type, so you can render anything Dojo can do. A good starting point is the [Dojo animation tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/animation/).

What you typically would do: load the list of images from a view or configuration document. To make that easy you use a repeat control to render exactly the output you need for your desired animation.

If you are looking at a [SlideShow](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/image/SlideShow.html), your repeat would use a [REST Store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#dojo-store-jsonrest) and the Rest service to pull your values (no repeat required then).

There are two ready to use controls on [OpenNTF](http://openNTF.org):

- [Image cube](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20ImageCube%20Custom%20Control)
- [Image slider](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Galleria%20Slider%20Control)

Hope that helps!